# Is it possible to "grey-out" a h:selectBooleanCheckbox ?

Tags: jsp, jsf

Currently I have conditions in my render attribute that decide whether the checkbox is displayed or not. Instead, I want the conditions to dictate whether the checkbox is clickable or greyed out (to indicate the user does not have permission to click it).

I am a complete noob to JSF.

Comment: add the disabled="true" attribute to it, so keep your rendered but have disabled="#{bean.someCondition}"

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;



@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyMB implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private boolean disabledCheckbox = false;

    public void toggle(){
        this.disabledCheckbox = !this.disabledCheckbox;
    }

    public boolean isDisabledCheckbox() {
        return disabledCheckbox;
    }

    public void setDisabledCheckbox(boolean disabledCheckbox) {
        this.disabledCheckbox = disabledCheckbox;
    }

}
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>

    <h:form>
        <p:panel>
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="cb" disabled="#{myMB.disabledCheckbox}"
                value="#{true}" />
            <p:commandButton action="#{myMB.toggle}" update="cb" />
        </p:panel>
    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```